# Float not being converted correctly

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I am working on a program that will convert from dollars to cents. I take in user input as a float using a predefined function then i try to multiply this float by 100 but it gives me an incorrect value. Heres the code:

```
printf("Change in dollars: ");
change= GetFloat();
cents= round(change*100);
printf("Cents is %f",cents);
```

This is a logical error because the program runs fine but there is something wrong with the mathematics for example if i enter 1.50 when prompted, the return i get is 1004 which is clearly wrong. What i want to happen is 150 to be outputted.

Comment: Please show `GetFloat()`. _and beware of floating-point math_, at times. :-)

Comment: What are the locale settings in your os?

Comment: Yeah please edit your question and add the function GetFloat()

Comment: What locale settings, and really post `GetFloat()` it's almost surely the problem.

Comment: See the http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @iharob .^^..here goes your answer... `i am using ubuntu ` :-)

Comment: @student1999 What is it that you want to do?Do you want to get the decimal part of the input or what?

Comment: i want to convert from dollars to cents

Comment: it sounds pretty straightforward but the answer provided by iharob seems a little too complex

Comment: @student1999 simply output the value of `change` to see if the input is your problem - then think about handling invalid input like iharob suggests

Comment: @student1999 sorry, why is it complex? Error checking is one of the most important and often ignored things a programmer should do.

Comment: Dear @ student1999 , somehow did you miss the first part of my _very_ first comment?

Comment: I can't be sure, because a lot of your code is missing, but it's likely that you have not properly declared everything as floating-point.  Your variables `change` and `cents` must be declared as `double` (or maybe `float`).  Your functions `GetFloat()` and `round()` must be declared (and defined) as returning `double` (or maybe `float`).  Please check these things.

Comment: Thank you guys! I found the error, it was that i previously declared all my variables as ints when some of them were supposed to be floats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because you have some locale where the decimal separator is `,` instead of `.`, and since you are very likely not checking the return value of `scanf()` "*which is what most books do and almost every tutorial*", then the variable is not being initialized and what you are printing is a consequence of the layout of your program instead of a value inputed by a user.

To verify what I say, I suggest compiling the same program without modification but with different compilation flags.

What you must do is ensure that the input is correct, try this

```
float GetFloat(int *ok)
 {
    float value = 0;
    if (scanf("%f", &value) != 1)
        *ok = 0;
    else
        *ok = 1;
    return value;
 }
```

which you would call like this

```
int   result = 0;
float change = GetFloat(&result);
if (result == 0)
    return -1;
float cents = round(change * 100);

printf("Cents is %f",cents);
```

If the decimal separator is an issue, the above program will not output anything, because `scanf()` will return `0`, and hence `ok` will be `0` after you call the function.

One important consequence of ignoring the return value of non-`void` functions is that if the value was not initialized like in this case with `scanf()`, and you don't know that because you didn't check the return value, then **undefined behavior** will happen, meaning that your program will contain bugs that are very difficult to find and hence very hard to fix.

Comment: how would i implement this in my code

Comment: @student1999 I don't know, because you didn't post your code.